# How to get the URL for a Dead Letter Queue for an SQS queue generated using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs, terraform-provider-aws, dead-letter

I can get the URL of an SQS queue by creating a Terraform Data Source like below,

```
data "aws_sqs_queue" "my-sqs-queue-name" {
  name = "my-sqs-queue-name"
}
```

and then by referring to it as,

```
QUEUE_URL = data.aws_sqs_queue.my-sqs-queue-name.url
```

How can I get the URL for the Dead Letter Queue created automatically with the above Queue?
I want something like the following. Is it even possible?

```
DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_URL = data.aws_sqs_queue.my-sqs-queue-name.dead_letter_queue.url
```

Comment: It is not an exported attribute of the data source, so probably not.

Comment: Thanks. @MattSchuchard. Makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Below is code to create a Dead letter queue and how to get SQS url using Terraform resource attributes and data source.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/sqs_queue.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/sqs_queue.html

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "example" {
  name   = "example"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs-queue-policy.json
  redrive_policy            = jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = aws_sqs_queue.example_dlq.arn
    maxReceiveCount     = 5
  })
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "example_dlq" {
  name = "example-dlq"
}

data "aws_sqs_queue" "example_dlq {
  name = "example-dlq"
}

output "sqs_url_data_source" {
  value = data.aws_sqs_queue.example_dlq.url
}

output "sqs_url_resource_attribute" {
  value = aws_sqs_queue.example.example_dlq.id
}

Or

DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_URL = aws_sqs_queue.example.example_dlq.id

DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_URL = data.aws_sqs_queue.example_dlq.url
```